# For a table of dates in a Google Spreadsheet, for each date, find the greatest date for the previous month and previous quarter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table of dates (not sorted). For each row, I need to find:

1. the `RANK` the `Report Date` is
2. the `Report Date`'s `Report Month`
3. the `Report Date`'s `Report Quarter`
4. the the immediate previous `Report Date`
5. the greatest `Report Date` in the immediate previous `Report Month`
6. the greatest `Report Date` in the immediate previous `Report Quarter`

I have 1-4 figured out. I'm not sure how to get 5 and 6.

Here is my data, and the various formulas I have:

| Report Date | Report Date Rank | Report Month | Report Quarter | Previous Report Date | Previous Month Report Date | Previous Quarter Report Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-19 | 8 | 2022-08 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-08-03 | ??? | ??? |
| 2022-06-08 | 15 | 2022-06 | 2022 Q2 | 2022-05-31 |  |  |
| 2022-09-23 | 2 | 2022-09 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-09-16 |  |  |
| 2022-07-18 | 12 | 2022-07 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-06-27 |  |  |
| 2022-08-26 | 6 | 2022-08 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-08-22 |  |  |
| 2022-09-30 | 1 | 2022-09 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-09-23 |  |  |
| 2022-08-03 | 9 | 2022-08 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-08-02 |  |  |
| 2022-09-09 | 4 | 2022-09 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-09-02 |  |  |
| 2022-09-16 | 3 | 2022-09 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-09-09 |  |  |
| 2022-06-27 | 13 | 2022-06 | 2022 Q2 | 2022-06-14 |  |  |
| 2022-06-14 | 14 | 2022-06 | 2022 Q2 | 2022-06-08 |  |  |
| 2022-05-31 | 16 | 2022-05 | 2022 Q2 | 2022-05-24 |  |  |
| 2022-07-26 | 11 | 2022-07 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-07-18 |  |  |
| 2022-08-22 | 7 | 2022-08 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-08-19 |  |  |
| 2022-04-26 | 18 | 2022-04 | 2022 Q2 |  |  |  |
| 2022-08-02 | 10 | 2022-08 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-07-26 |  |  |
| 2022-05-24 | 17 | 2022-05 | 2022 Q2 | 2022-04-26 |  |  |
| 2022-09-02 | 5 | 2022-09 | 2022 Q3 | 2022-08-26 |  |  |

Formulas:

- `B1`:

  ```
  ={
      "Report Date Rank";
      ARRAYFORMULA(
          IF(
              A2:A <> "",
              RANK(
                  A2:A,
                  A:A
              ),
          )
      )
  }
  ```
- `C1`:

  ```
  ={
      "Report Month";
      ARRAYFORMULA(
          IF(
              A2:A <> "",
              TEXT(A2:A, "YYYY-MM"),
          )
      )
  }
  ```
- `D1`:

  ```
  ={
      "Report Quarter";
      ARRAYFORMULA(
          IF(
              A2:A <> "",
              YEAR(A2:A) & " Q" & ROUNDUP(MONTH(A2:A)/3, 0),
          )
      )
  }
  ```
- `E1`:

  ```
  ={
      "Previous Report Date";
      ARRAYFORMULA(
          IF(
              A2:A <> "",
              XLOOKUP(
                  B2:B + 1,
                  B:B,
                  A:A,
              ),
          )
      )
  }
  ```

For 5 and 6, I was thinking I could `RANK` the `Report Month` and `Report Quarter` columns, but I don't know how to use that information to get the greatest date in the previous "rank".

So, for example, for 5, for the row with `2022-08-19` for `Report Date`, 5 and 6 would be:

- `Previous Month Report Date` = `2022-07-26` because that is the greatest `Report Date` in the `2022-08-19`'s previous month

  - `2022-08-19`'s `Report Month` is `2022-08`
  - The previous `Report Month` is `2022-07`
  - The largest `Report Date` in `2022-07` is `2022-07-26`
- `Previous Quarter Report Date` = `2022-06-27` because that is the greatest `Report Date` in the `2022-08-19`'s previous quarter

  - `2022-08-19`'s `Report Quarter` is `2022 Q3`
  - The previous `Report Quarter` is `2022 Q2`
  - The largest `Report Date` in `2022 Q2` is `2022-06-27`

Comment: You statement of problem is not clear. Can you explain little more?

Comment: I added some details. I hope that helps?

Comment: Kindly ask one question per post. Have you tried `SORT+VLOOKUP` or `SORT+INDEX/MATCH` with different `is_sorted` arguments?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Please share your failed approach one at time, you structure the problem very well for some one to solve it but not for this site, limit the questions to only 1. see [Should posts be self-contained?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18669/should-posts-be-self-contained)

Comment: I am a bit confused as I have only asked one question.

Comment: @Osm I am unsure of what you're saying. My question is structured very well but not for this site?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan This question should be divided 1 for previous month 2 for previous quarter, I ment by structured very well...; the question is detailed and good but needs to present what your approach to solve the problem for future visitors, this way they most likely relate to the question problem.

Comment: I see. Someone was able to understand it and answer it so I'm good for now. I will keep your feedback in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try approximate match (next smallest) on the sorted dates:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,xlookup(eomonth(A2:A,-1),sort(A2:A),sort(A2:A),,-1)))
```

and

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,xlookup(eomonth(A2:A,-(mod(month(A2:A)-1,3)+1)),sort(A2:A),sort(A2:A),,-1)))
```

[image]

*EDIT*

On reading the small print of Xlookup, I can see that sorting is actually unneccessary because it does *not* assume array is in order unless you specify 2 as the last argument [see docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947?hl=en) so this also works

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,xlookup(eomonth(A2:A,-1),A2:A,A2:A,,-1)))
```

Comment: This is the most clever thing I've seen all week. Thank you. This gives me so many ideas for other formulas I have.

Comment: You're welcome - glad it worked for you.